# AutoHotKey Script to change Switchy Proxy in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, autohotkey

I want to write an autohotkey script to change the proxy settings in Switchy for Chrome. 
If I could access the extension execution scope, I could call a function there. Is there any way to do that in chrome?
Is there a better way to write a autohotkey script to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean, you want to access to the code behind the extension/app (back-end) **in Windows** you    can try this:

Go to your Google Chrome installation path, commonly:

```
"C:\Documents and Settings\%USER%\Program File\Google\Chrome\%User Data%\Default\Extensions\%Extension ID%\"
```

Then you copy and paste elsewhere all files of the extension (in this case ***Switchy***)
and modify it as you want.

PS. Sorry for my English

Comment: The code for switchy is freely available on code.google.com... what I need to be able to do is either run the extension outside of chrome, or programmaticly control it inside chrome.

Comment: You mean, something like an desktop app based on Switchy for Chrome?

Comment: Something like this could help you:

[ProxySwitch](http://code.google.com/p/proxyswitch/), written in C# using .NET 3.5 framework.

or
 
[AutoProxSwitcher](http://code.google.com/p/autoproxyswitcher/), based on rules defined in a xml config file